# Alternative for wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: pdf, css

**Question**: Are there alternatives to `wkhtmltopdf`?

**Why**: `wkhtmltopdf` is converting my css wrong, do not show the `background` property of a div

Comment: Can you give more details about the background property that is not shown in the PDF?
You should get everything shown in the html unless you have a "display:none" in a print.css I would try to solve the wkhtmltopdf before trying other more complex solutions.

Comment: The question is almost 2 years old, could you find a decent replacement?

Comment: @ringo no, I could not

Answer (score 0):

**php-dompdf**

It is available only in [Trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=php-dompdf)

Can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install php-dompdf fonts-dejavu php-font-lib php5 sdop
```